# How can I send variables from my Controller to my scss in Symfony 6 Encore

Tags: symfony, sass, twig, webpack-encore

I have a controller that sends user variables to a twig template, currently i'm doing inline css to add a background color which is being fetched through the database (different per user)

I'm using symfony encore to learn more regarding webpack and scss, how can I send the parameter `{{ color }}` to create variable or to use it inside my app.scss?

Comment: I don't know you can as it's not a template, maybe you can create variable into your twig that will be used by css

Comment: in my twig I have {{ color }}, how can I pass it to my app.scss file which is compiled by webpack? maybe through js?

Comment: You could use CSS(3) variables and define the variable in your template? `<style>:root { --custom-color : {{ color }}; }</style>`? I don't think `twig` can interfere with/tweak SASS

Comment: This works @DarkBee thanks, I thought to use in the scss variables, but for now I think this solves it