# Compile Tailwind classes based on Twig variable

Tags: twig, tailwind-css

Let's say I've set a variable in Twig based based on a condition. Now I want to use the output of the variable as class like this:

```
{% set color = test ? 'text-black' : 'text-white' %}
<div class="{{ color }}">test</div>
```

Is it possible to only compile the right class based on the Twig condition instead of both classes?

Comment: [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76338918/how-can-i-send-variables-from-my-controller-to-my-scss-in-symfony-6-encore)

Answer (score 1):

Tailwind builds the CSS at **build time**, but template code would happen **later** at **run time**. Further more, Tailwind does not *evaluate* code it scans, but rather reviews it as plain text files so that it is language-agnostic.

Presumably, you'd want both classes compiled in your CSS, since you'd want to style the falsey and truthy cases. Otherwise, you could:

- Have only the case you'd like to style have a class, e.g. for truthy only:

  ```
  {% set color = test ? 'text-black' : '' %}
  ```
- Use [`blocklist`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#discarding-classes) in the Tailwind configuration to not generate the CSS rule for the unwanted class:

  ```js
  module.exports = {
    // …
    blocklist: [
      'text-white',
    ],
  }
  ```

Comment: That makes sense. But what if I've got a config where a user can select a setting and based on this setting a style should be applied? I then only want to compile the selected style setting instead of all the style options.

Comment: You could consider using a CSS variable so that only one rule is generated but the value itself changes at run-time.